# Too many parameters when calling functions

Tags: javascript

I am calling some functions where I end up passing so many arguments it is getting silly! Is this some type of code smell and suggests I am doing things incorrectly? Is there a better way of structuring things?

Example:

```
checkMyData(
    string1,
    string2,
    string3,
    string4,
    string5,
    string6,
    string7,
    string8,
    string9,
    arrayData1,
    arrayData2,
    arrayData3,
    arrayData4,
    arrayData5,
    arrayData6,
    arrayData7,
    arrayData8,
    arrayData9
  );
```

Comment: Yes.. This gets inconvenient over time. Without knowing more details and with the information at hand, I'd suggest you pass a single parameter as an object. This object would contain all the properties you're passing in as parameters...

Comment: Hi! you can use kwargs to pass many arguments. try:

```checkMyData(**{
    'string1': string1,
    'string2': string2,
   ' string3': string3,...})```

This (**) make a mapping from keys to params with their values

Comment: Another thing you should look at is the `arguments` object in JS.  But that would still require you to pass that many parameters to the function at calling time... 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: @CristianContrera, that would be Python syntax. Here we are dealing with JavaScript.

Comment: If there's one string per data array then you could pass two parameters: the first is an array of strings, the second is the corresponding array of data arrays. Or pass one parameter which is an array of objects, each object having one string and its corresponding array of data.

Comment: Or perhaps a single parameter which is an object that maps the N string values to their corresponding data arrays e.g. `{ 'james': [10,14,22], 'mary': [20,14,18] }`

Comment: Whenever you start numbering your variable names, **use an array**! This is indeed very smelly code. It reeks that not just the parameter declaration and the function calls have this problem, but also the code inside the function.

Comment: @Bergi The actual variable and array names are just to illustrate a point.

Comment: I quite like the object idea. Instead of me having a big long list of let statements, I could have myObj and pass myObj instead of that massive long list of arguments. Then in the function, to access each individual bit of data, I presume I just use myObj.string7 and so on? Also, what I am not clear on is when I should be using variables (or objects) vs state. Any quick explanation to clarify that?

Comment: @Jon In that case, please post your actual code (including the function body, and ideally even some example invocations) instead of a made-up example

Comment: This looks like it should be `checkMyData(strings, arrayDatas)` where `strings` and `arrayDatas` are arrays.  You could even call it as `checkMyData(...strings, ...arrayDatas)`.  And you can write the function as `checkMyData(...args)` or make use of the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object.

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
checkMyData(
   stringArgs,
    arrayArgs
  );
```

and pass them as arrays?

Other option:

```js
function checkMyData(...args) {
  const stringArgs = args.filter(x => typeof x === 'string')
  const nonStringArgs = args.filter(x => typeof x !== 'string')
  console.log(stringArgs)
  console.log(nonStringArgs)
  }
  
 checkMyData('a','b','c',[1,2,3],[4,5,6])
```

Comment: I am wondering if I should be using an object instead of a big list of independent variables. Early in my App() function I have a big list of variables set with let statements. Instead, should I be using an object that contains all these variables?